# Save date in cassandra with spring

Tags: spring, date, cassandra

I am trying to save the date automatically in cassandra through spring, for which I change the type of date that I get with spring (Date) to the format of Cassandra (Date yyyy-mm-dd)

**Controller**

```
@PostMapping("/add")
public ResponseEntity<Cliente> crearCliente(@RequestBody Cliente cliente) {
    Date fecha = new Date();
    System.out.println(fecha);
    long lnMilisegundos = fecha.getTime();
    java.sql.Date sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(lnMilisegundos);

    cliente.setCreateAt(sqlDate);
    cliente.setUpdateAt(sqlDate);

    return clienteSevicio.crearCliente(cliente);
}
```

**Service**

```
@Override
public ResponseEntity<Cliente> crearCliente(Cliente cliente) {
    try {
        System.out.println(((Object)cliente.getCreateAt()).getClass().getSimpleName());
        System.out.println(cliente.getCreateAt());
        Cliente _cliente = clienteRepositorio.save(new Cliente(UUIDs.timeBased(), cliente.getNombre(), cliente.getApellido(), cliente.getEmail(), cliente.getCreateAt(), cliente.getUpdateAt()));
        return new ResponseEntity<>(_cliente, HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }catch (Exception e ) {
        System.out.printf("Error");
        System.out.println(e);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(null, HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    }
}
```

I am printing by console the type of data and the data (the date) to see if they are correct and it prints the following: Date 2020-10-02

But it is also printing me the error which is:

```
Errororg.springframework.data.cassandra.CassandraInvalidQueryException: SessionCallback; CQL [INSERT INTO clientes (apellido,create_at,email,id,nombre,update_at) VALUES ('string',1601646868204,'string3',c9ee78e0-04b6-11eb-bfa7-39627886e1eb,'string2',1601646868204);]; Expected 4 byte long for date (8); nested exception is com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.InvalidQueryException: Expected 4 byte long for date (8)
```

Seeing the error, it is passing me the date "1601646868204" when it should be "2020-10-02", why is this happening? what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try to use com.datastax.driver.core.LocalDate instead of java.sql.Date

Answer (score 0):

Basically, when you defined:

```
long lnMilisegundos = fecha.getTime();
java.sql.Date sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(lnMilisegundos);
```

the value that will be stored in the sqlDate variable is the millisecond related to the date that you are using.
According to the java.sql.Date definition:

> A thin wrapper around a millisecond value that allows JDBC to identify this as an SQL DATE value. A millisecond's value represents the number of milliseconds that have passed since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00.000 GMT.

You need to use another type or format your milliseconds variable to YYYY-MM-DD (year - month- date)